# How to start a countdown timer when app is initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, jwt, dio

A jwt is generated from the backend after user logs in. The Token only lasts for 60secs before expiry. I want the token to refresh in 10secs to expire. I want a timer that will countdown from Token time 10secs and then call the refreshToken method.
I don't want to use Dio 401 interceptor due to security reasons. The jwt is needed to authorize the refresh token endpoint and generate a new jwt.

Example:
When user logs in successfully, countdown timer should start from 60secs of jwt expiry time to 10secs before it expire and call the refresh Token method.

I couldn't come up with a better solution for the countdown timer logic, I tried using difference in time to check the differences in current time and Token expiry time but its not working.

This is the countdown timer method in homepage.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    tokenTimer();
    super.initState();
  }

  RestartableTimer? timer;
  var counter = 0.obs;
  Future<void> tokenTimer() async {
    print("User Token Initialized");
    const secs = Duration(seconds: 1);
    final storage = GetStorage();
    var token = await storage.read("Token");
    var tokenExpiry = JwtDecoder.getExpirationDate(token);
    var currentTime = DateTime.now();
    var diff = tokenExpiry.difference(currentTime).inSeconds.obs;
    print(diff);
    timer = RestartableTimer(
      secs,
      (() {
        if (diff.value == 10) {
          print('REFRESHING TOKING');
          timer?.cancel();
          ApiService.refreshToken().whenComplete(() => timer?.reset());
        } else {
          diff.value--;
        }
      }),
    );
  }
```

Refresh Token method

```
  static Future<void> refreshToken() async {
    final token = await _storage.read('Token');
    _client.options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    _client.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
    final response = await _client.post('/refresh');
    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      final newAccessToken = response.data['Token'];
      print('New Token: $newAccessToken');
      _storage.write('Token', newAccessToken);
    } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      performLogout();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't want to use a timer to refresh the JWT you can use interceptors for handling the token expires. If you are using the http packages you have http interceptors, This will handle the JWT token refresh.

Comment: I think the interceptor only works when making request to the API. The JWT maybe expired before the request will be made causing a 401. Is there a better way to refresh the JWT before expiration using interceptor?

Comment: Yes when you get the 401. Then do the jwt refresh that's how the logic works

Comment: That's not what exactly i am looking for. Soon as the jwt expires, then user need to login again to generate fresh token. The jwt can only refresh when not expired yet because i will use the token to authorize the refreshToken endpoint before getting a new jwt.